# Trying to get NSTimers to synchronise when they are fired swift

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am trying to create a game where the user has to navigate a ball through gaps in platforms (known as fall down). When the score reaches a certain point, the moving platforms are created at a faster rate. To achieve this I wrote the code below:

```
switch String(level) {

                        case "1" :
                            beginLevel.invalidate()
                            level1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 0.9 , target: self, selector: Selector("platformCreation"), userInfo: nil , repeats: true)

                        case "2" :
                            level1.invalidate()
                            level2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 0.8 , target: self, selector: Selector("platformCreation"), userInfo: nil , repeats: true)

                        case "3" :
                            level2.invalidate()
                            level3 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 0.7 , target: self, selector: Selector("platformCreation"), userInfo: nil , repeats: true)

                        case "4" :
                            level3.invalidate()
                            level4 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 0.6 , target: self, selector: Selector("platformCreation"), userInfo: nil , repeats: true)

                        default :
                           print("invalid level")
                        }
```

beginLevel is ran whenever the game restarts, and level can only be 1- 4.

The issue I am having with this is that once the previous NSTimer is invalided, there is a delay where no platforms are created, before the new one is fired. These delays make the game too easy and in all honestly it looks ugly too! Which I'm trying to achieve is a constant flow of platforms with no huge gaps between platforms. Anything you can offer to this issue is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to invalidate the old timer after an appropriate delay.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.level1.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Similar to the issue i had with the other answer, i think I need to change level based on a timer rather than when the score reaches 20. because the timer can fire at any point when score of 20 is reached. However this has been useful in coding my power ups so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use call fire() method immediately after initializing of timer as give below

```
level3 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 0.7 , target: self, selector: Selector("platformCreation"), userInfo: nil , repeats: true);
level.fire()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, i believe it is an issue where the platforms are out of sych because the score can change at any point. I realise the issue may be i need to change level based on time rather than score